# lxml and <noscript> in <head>

Tags: python, lxml, noscript, lxml.html

I got a strange bug with lxml:

```
>>> s = '<html><head><noscript></noscript><script></script><meta></head></html>' 
>>> root = lxml.html.fromstring(s)
>>> root.xpath('/html/head/meta')
>>> root.xpath('/html/body/meta')
[<Element meta at 0x2a92788>]
```

meta tag should in head element, not body. How can I get correct element in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess: are you using old version of Ubuntu (like 12.04)?
Actually, it's a bug in old version of preinstalled `libxml2` library used by lxml package. In the [release notes](http://www.xmlsoft.org/news.html) for version 2.8.0 they mention fix for `HTML parser error with <noscript> in the <head>` - so I guess version of libxml2 >= 2.8.0 should work. Ubuntu 12.04 has version 2.7.8 installed.

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> lxml.etree.LIBXML_COMPILED_VERSION
(2, 7, 8)
>>> lxml.etree.LIBXML_VERSION
(2, 9, 1)
```

I think if any of these versions are >=2.8.0, the `<noscript>`
 issue should be gone.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
import lxml.html

s = '<html><head><noscript></noscript><script></script><meta></head></html>' 
root = lxml.html.fromstring(s)
print(root.xpath('/html/head/meta'))
print(root.xpath('/html/body/meta'))
```

**Output:**

```
[<Element meta at 0x10a123b8>]
[]
```

I'm using Python 2.7.9 and lxml version 3.4.2.

Comment: But I got this error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'html'`

Comment: Check which lxml version you are using with `from lxml import etree`, `etree.LXML_VERSION`. I'm struggling to replicate your problem

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.3 and LXML 3.4.4

Comment: I'll try to upgrade Python later and re-check again. Thanks!

Comment: @Kid, re your **AttributeError**, try relative imports: `from lxml import html` and change the usage of `lxml.html.fromstring` to `html.fromstring`.

Comment: @Anzel: Thanks! But I think the problem is about Python version. I upgraded Python to 2.7.6 but no luck.